# is it possible to simulate a stopwatch with IsHighResolution = false when by default it's true?

Tags: .net

Is it possible to simulate a stopwatch with IsHighResolution = false when by default it's true?

Comment: What is "simulate" supposed to mean?  Is "stopwatch" intentionally written without a capital-S?  Does your ISP charge you a high rate for long messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx) and a quick look in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm), I will offer a tentative **no**.

Here's the relevant part from the documentation:

> The timer used by the Stopwatch class depends on the system hardware and operating system.

`IsHighResolution` is a read-only field which is initialized by the (static) type initializer via a call to the `QueryPerformanceFrequency` Win32 API function (apparently from kernel32.dll).

If there's any way of changing this, I can't think of it it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Mark says, the documentation also says

> Otherwise, IsHighResolution is false,
>   which indicates that the Stopwatch
>   timer is based on the system timer.

I guess it means, you could use a regular timer.
See if this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) helps you.

EDIT: Looking into reflector, it seems that the code relies on `DateTime.Ticks` if it is not a high resolution timer to start/stop.